# Should I be 100% truthful while writing my Personal Statement for Graduate application?

Tags: statement-of-purpose

Let us think about this question in my online application.

> Personal Statement:
>
> Please describe your specific area of academic interest, and explain what motivated you to choose this area.

In my case 100% true answer would be the following,

> I am interested in Image Processing.
>
> When I was searching for a supervisor, I met one of the most prominent research professors of the XYZ University Prof. xyz who works in the area of Image Processing, Computer Vision, Graphics and so on. I was interested in Computer Graphics and proposed his a topic. He told me that topic was not fit for MSc thesis to be completed in 4 months. That would actually take more time may be up to a year. Since, I didn't have any other topic in my mind, I requested him to propose a topic for me. He then proposed a topic related to Image Processing. I found that topic very interesting and saw a huge opportunity to learn about the area of Image Processing from the inside.

Is that a good answer?

Comment: You can be truthful with less detail.  "My master's advisor suggested a topic in image processing and I ..."

Comment: Upon more careful reading (sorry!) I see that it was a "prominent researcher" and not your advisor.  That will change the words, but not the idea.  *Um,* and be sure to use standard capitalization when you write your statement of purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Bob version of your paragraph is a good start.  But if you want to make an impact on the admissions committee, you're going to have to find out a lot more about your topic, so that you can speak about it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should always tell the truth. But you are not in a court of law. You don't have to tell the whole truth, all the time.

Your area of academic interest is image processing. So: Explain why you are interested in *that*. Right now you are telling a story about how you got a thesis topic. Once you have told that story, you can explain how you are happy to have found a professor who provided you with a thesis topic related to your area of academic interest, but with a scope matching a Masters thesis.